# Logistic regression: computing ratio of OR and confidence interval of the ratio

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio, ratio

If I have OR(A vs B) and OR(C vs B), the ratio of the OR is equal to OR(A vs C).

But, how to I compute the confidence interval for the ratio of OR?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $OR = \frac{A\times B}{C\times D}$, the 95% confidence interval is given by the formula:

$$e^{\log(OR) \pm [1.96 \times \text{SE}(\log(OR))]}$$

This is because the log odds ratio is Normally distributed (with mean $\text{log}(OR)$). This allows us to set up the 95% CI in a familiar way.

First calculate $\log(OR)$. Then get $\text{SE}(\log(OR)) \approx \sqrt{\frac{1}{A} +\frac{1}{B}+\frac{1}{C}+\frac{1}{D}}$. Note that your sample size should be sufficiently large for the approximation to hold.